# Problem dual booting Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dual-boot

I tried dual booting into Linux Mint, and I got an error saying I was missing a file. I can't say it because it triggers the grammar detection thing.

I thought it thought my operating system was windows, and it was missing a master boot record, until I realized that those files were supported by Linux only. I have looked at tutorials, and it assumes I encountered this problem when I was trying to boot up windows.

Is there any way to fix the black screen of death? I know this might look like a duplicate but I don't think I can run Linux code, which was the answer for pretty much all questions like this.

Comment: the file was ubnldr.mbr, and i was using UNetbootin

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You can't boot into anything? Does GRUB show up at all?

Comment: correction, can't boot into linux, can boot in windows

Answer (score 0):

People tend to have trouble with UNetbootin. Hopefully, you have another device, where you can remake your live USB using another program like Rufus. I don't recommend using UNetbootin again.

Source: [Unetbootin not working with Ubuntu 16.04.3 for me](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/7l6vf7/unetbootin_not_working_with_ubuntu_16043_for_me/)

It turns out OP doesn't have a USB. Here is another solution:

You can boot into Windows 10, as I've learnt. Windows 10 has their own disc burning tool, so you can use that, here are the steps:

1. Insert your blank CD/DVD (remove the previous contents of the Linux Mint ISO.)
2. Open File Explorer
3. Navigate to the ISO file
4. Right click on the ISO file and choose "Burn disk image". This will open 'Windows Disk Image Burner".
5. Choose the burner you want to use, click "Burn" and wait for it to finish.

Source: [Steps to Easily Burn an ISO to a CD/DVD or USB](https://appuals.com/steps-to-easily-burn-an-iso-to-a-cddvd-or-usb/)

I've learnt that UNetbootin has an option to store the file as a live system on the hard drive and boot it from there. I've recommended OP to get a USB or use another program which can do the same, because UNetbootin has caused people problems in the past, more so than any other live USB maker I've seen.

Comment: i would probably accept this, if i wasn't using UNetbootin because i don't have a usb

Comment: Oh, so you made a live CD? Would've liked to known that before.

Comment: No, i was using it because it had a hard drive option

Comment: Please edit your question so I know what media you used (CD, DVD, USB, etc.)

Comment: none, i didn't use any, UNetbootin has an option for people who don't want a usb to use a harddrive to store the linux distro

Comment: Oh. Alright. Please get a USB, or find another program which allows you to store it on the hard drive. UNetbootin has caused a few people problems.

Comment: okay, i'll get one